# Difference between domain reseller and domain registrar?

Tags: dns

I have heard terms "domain reseller" and "domain registrar" and that "domain registrar" is better than "domain reseller". What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registrars are the companies that actually buy licenses to sell TLD's at a registry (those who manage the DNS server for a TLD) such as Verisign for `.com`. Domain resellers, often hosting companies, resell these TLD's from a registrar as it's much cheaper - otherwise hosting companies would have to buy licenses to sell TLD's themselves, which is extremely expensive.

Comment: "Domain resellers, for example hosting companies" - some hosting companies are domain registrars as well.

Comment: @w3d You're right.

Answer (score 3):

Being a domain name registrar, I can confirm there is no requirements for networks, DNS servers and so on.

> A domain name registrar is an organization or commercial entity that
>   manages the reservation of Internet domain names. A domain name
>   registrar must be accredited by a generic top-level domain (gTLD)
>   registry and/or a country code top-level domain (ccTLD) registry.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar

A reseller is someone who simply resells the domain registration service, they are not domain name registrars themselves.

Comment: I find your statement that there are no requirements for network or DNS a serious overstatement. Just reading the ICAAN requirements makes this notion impossible. https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en

Comment: The little link you posted on my 3 year old comment doesnt work. & unsurprisingly - you are wrong. http://registrars.nominet.uk/registration-and-domain-management/registrar-agreement

Comment: The ICANN link works and your reply with a specific registry agreement does not make a point. Also the start "networks, DNS servers" is vague (a registrar does not necessarily provide DNS service, etc.), so difficult to argue. But in short (and as you start with authority I can say I work in registries and registrars since 20 years) various registries can force technical and non technical constraints to registrars, including even things similar to ISO27001 certification. You can count on the bar being always put higher on things like that.

Comment: Its probable that your response to a 6 year old question clicked on a link that indeed wasnt working at the time of comment response 3 years ago. My link did make a point, it proved that at the time of writing, a domain name registrar did not require "networks, DNS servers, support, and so on." as was suggested elsewhere on the page. My response did not attempt to cover all possible registrars and any changes in the future. You could make a fresh answer if you have new information.

Answer (score 1):

Domain registrars are required to have certain infrastructure elements such as networks, DNS servers, support, and so on. Resellers resell through registrars and are not required to have anything much at all. Think of a reseller as an affiliate.

Comment: Thanks! Just to give an example, are the well-known brands like Godaddy or Network Solutions resellers of VeriSign Global Registry Services for .com TLD?

Comment: Network Solutions is VeriSign- the same company with a new(ish) name and GogDaddy is the original competition to Network Solutions and Thank God(!) for that too because Network Solutions was charging $49 per domain name per year with no breaks in the price. When I was a web host, I switched over to GoDaddy faster than a jack rabbit! My experience with them has been flawless. I could not say that with Network Solutions. But I had an advantage with NetSol in that they wanted me to work for them at the highest level since they could not recruit Cricket Liu. I could always get my stuff fixed.

Comment: @closetnoc Domains are the only thing GoDaddy doesn't suck at ;)

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards That's all I use them for. I think most web hosts are terrible these days. People ran to the lowest price or free cutting out the web hosts that gave a damn (like me). How is RackSpace? They made me a hefty offer about 7 years ago.

Comment: @closetnoc I agree. It's quite easy to start a crappy host these days... :(

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards My tech support phone number was my cell phone! That was how much personal service people got. My business partner and I took care of all issues and had advanced monitoring tools and fail over that does not exist today anywhere. Our connectivity was a direct connection to MAE-East and MAE-West. Problems were only ever a blip on the screen and rarely happened. Oh well. It became too hard to convince people of what power they were buying for a small price and making money too much of a hassle.

Comment: @closetnoc I know what you're talking about... ;-)

Comment: @Martin You can find at https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accreditation-qualified-list.html the official and up to date list of ICANN accredited registrars which are companies allowed to sell gTLDs and being under contract with gTLD registries (but companies names can vary between their commercial name and their official/business one). As for ccTLDs, it is highly probable that each registry maintains somewhere a public list of its registrars, but you have to search on each registry websites.